# Add new row to bottom of jQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I got a jqgrid with inline edit, and the possibility to add new rows.

At the moment the new rows are displayed in "edit" mode at the top of the grid. What I want is to add the new row to the bottom of the grid since my "Add new row" button is in a custom bottompager...

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `position` option of [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) which you typically specify by `addParams` option of [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#inlinenav):

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid("inlineNav", "#pager", {addParams: {position: "last"}});
```

See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/InlineEditingInlineNav1.htm) for the corresponding demo.

Comment: I am expecting similar, but more feature described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800565/add-and-edit-in-grid-with-jqgrid

Comment: @Oleg: When the new row is added, I notice the ID is always `new_row`. This could cause some issues with selecting, editing, etc. Is there a way to have a new ID generated or used on each Add Row click? Let me know if you think this question deserves it's own post.

Comment: @Oleg: Ok, I just now found a way around this. On the `loadComplete` I get the last row's ID, then on each `addRow` event, I pass the last row's ID + 1 as a parameter, so that it will always append a new row with the grid's last ID + 1. If you have a better approach, I'd like to hear it, Oleg!

Comment: @FastTrack: The where *many* ways to set unique rowid for new row. It's better if you describes your problem more detailed in new question. Which version of jqGrid you use? Do you save editing data on the server of use `editurl: 'clientArray'`? Do you use `inlineNav` or you call `addRow` directly ? ...

Comment: @FastTrack: Usage of `ID + 1` seems not save if you allows to delete rows.